# Match columns with rows from different data frames without using a unique ID

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, match

I have two large data frames df1 & df2

**df1**

```
ID ...other columns...MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
1                     8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 6.0 0.0
2                     9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 6.0 6.0
4                     6.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 5.0 0.0
```

**df2**

```
Day Hours
FRI   0
SAT   0
SUN   0
MON   0
TUE   0
WED   0
THU   0
FRI   0
SAT   0
SUN   0
MON   0
TUE   0
WED   0
...Will keep going until end about 28-31 days listed
```

I am trying to replace the Hours column in df2 with the corresponding times in df1 (Matching df1 column day names with the names in the day column in df2). df2 would fill using the first row of data in df1 until all rows in df2 have been filled then move onto the next row (loop through)...the idea being once 1st row has been filled, before moving onto the next, I would do a Sum of the 'Hours' column in df2 and then put that number back in df1 in a seperate column next to first row and so on...

**df2 1st output**

```
Day   Hours
FRI   8.5
SAT   6.0
SUN   0
MON   8.5
TUE   8.5
WED   8.5
THU   8.5
FRI   8.5
SAT   6.0
SUN   0
MON   8.5
TUE   8.5
WED   8.5
...will continue all the way until last row until all data is filled from 1st row in df1 (repeating itself, just matching the right values with rows)
```

**df1 1st output**

```
ID ...other columns...MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN Total
1                     8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 6.0 0.0 88.5
2                     9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 6.0 6.0
4                     6.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 5.0 0.0
```

...notice the Total is only from the Hours column in df2 which is only populated from data in the the corresponding row

**df2 2nd output**

```
Day   Hours
FRI   9.0
SAT   6.0
SUN   6.0
MON   9.0
TUE   9.0
WED   9.0
THU   9.0
FRI   9.0
SAT   6.0
SUN   6.0
MON   9.0
TUE   9.0
WED   9.0
```

...once first row in df1 has filled all df2 and a sum has been made then it would clean the Hours column and refill but now with row 2 of df1...doing the same thing until all rows in df2 has been filled

**df1 2nd output**

```
ID ...other columns...MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN Total
1                     8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 6.0 0.0 88.5
2                     9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 6.0 6.0 105
4                     6.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 5.0 0.0
```

...notice now the Total is only from the Hours column in df2 which is only populated from data in the the corresponding row

This continues for every line in df1 - which is about 1400 lines

So I am trying to sort out the matching/looping part of this but can't seem to get to a solution that works. Is there a way of doing this? I have been suggested using Matches, Joins, Left, Right Outer etc...but I am unsure how this would be used without a unique number ID and how would loop through the data frame

Many thanks

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding So df2 cotinues to repeat itself a set number of times (max 31 times)...the idea is that I need it to loop that amount times until end of row in df2 with data from the first row in df1 being plotted...once the first row from df1 has filled all of df2 then it moves onto the 2nd row in df1 and does the exact same thing...I hope that makes sense

Comment: I added a solution but not sure if fits your goal, please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option, hope this can help

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[
  melt(
    df1,
    id = "ID"
  )[order(ID)][
    ,
    .SD[df2, .(SumHours = sum(value)),
      on = .(variable = Day)
    ], ID
  ],
  on = .(ID)
]
```

- Output

```
   ID MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN SumHours
1:  1 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5   6   0       57
2:  2 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0   6   6       66
```

---

If you need to show check how two data tables are merged into one, you can try

```
melt(
  df1,
  id = "ID",
  value.name = "Hours"
)[order(ID)][
  ,
  .SD[df2,
    on = .(variable = Day)
  ], ID
][, i.Hours := NULL][]
```

which gives

```
    ID variable Hours
 1:  1      FRI   8.5
 2:  1      SAT   6.0
 3:  1      SUN   0.0
 4:  1      MON   8.5
 5:  1      TUE   8.5
 6:  1      WED   8.5
 7:  1      THU   8.5
 8:  1      FRI   8.5
 9:  2      FRI   9.0
10:  2      SAT   6.0
11:  2      SUN   6.0
12:  2      MON   9.0
13:  2      TUE   9.0
14:  2      WED   9.0
15:  2      THU   9.0
16:  2      FRI   9.0
```

---

**UPDATE**
I am not sure if the code below is exactly what you are after

```
df1out <- df1[, Total := rowSums(.SD)]

df2out <- lapply(split(melt(
  df1,
  id = "ID",
  value.name = "Hours"
)[order(ID)][
  ,
  .SD[df2,
    on = .(variable = Day)
  ], ID
][, i.Hours := NULL], by = "ID"), function(x) x[, ID := NULL])
```

such that

```
> df1out
   ID MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN Total
1:  1 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5 8.5   6   0  49.5
2:  2 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0 9.0   6   6  59.0
3:  4 6.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0   5   0  43.0

> df2out
$`1`
    variable Hours
 1:      FRI   8.5
 2:      SAT   6.0
 3:      SUN   0.0
 4:      MON   8.5
 5:      TUE   8.5
 6:      WED   8.5
 7:      THU   8.5
 8:      FRI   8.5
 9:      SAT   6.0
10:      SUN   0.0
11:      MON   8.5
12:      TUE   8.5
13:      WED   8.5

$`2`
    variable Hours
 1:      FRI     9
 2:      SAT     6
 3:      SUN     6
 4:      MON     9
 5:      TUE     9
 6:      WED     9
 7:      THU     9
 8:      FRI     9
 9:      SAT     6
10:      SUN     6
11:      MON     9
12:      TUE     9
13:      WED     9

$`4`
    variable Hours
 1:      FRI     7
 2:      SAT     5
 3:      SUN     0
 4:      MON     6
 5:      TUE     7
 6:      WED     7
 7:      THU     7
 8:      FRI     7
 9:      SAT     5
10:      SUN     0
11:      MON     6
12:      TUE     7
13:      WED     7
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 4L), MON = c(8.5, 9, 6), TUE = c(8.5,
9, 7), WED = c(8.5, 9, 7), THU = c(8.5, 9, 7), FRI = c(8.5, 9,
7), SAT = c(6, 6, 5), SUN = c(0, 6, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Day = c("FRI", "SAT", "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED",
"THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED"), Hours = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,       
-13L))
```

Comment: This is great Thomas thank you, a bit different from the desired solution so would there be a way perhaps if the next row (ID 2) in df1 doesn't attach to the end of df2...instead the entire df2 will be filled only with the first row (ID 1) from df1 until df2 is full (its okay to repeat the values until full because df2 willl have about 30 days running from MON:SUN)...so perhaps a row count on df2 and df1 row will fill all until complete then move onto the next row in df1...However before moving onto the next row in df1 it would sum the total in df2 Hours and amend back to df1 end of first row.

Comment: Keep in mind that df2 doesnt just run from FRI to FRI...it continues for another 30 times or less/more...will be dynamic depending on the loaded file...so it just needs to align all days with df1 1st row until all is filled (end of row) then move onto the next row in df1 and refill...summing each time

Comment: @Daisy Could you show a desired output in your post? I have no idea from your description only.

Comment: I have added the desired output/steps in the post - I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Thomas, does those new outputs make any sense of it?

Answer (score 0):

Joining can help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df1 %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  filter(ID==1) %>%
  left_join(df2,by = c('name'='Day')) %>%
  mutate(Hours=value) %>%
  select(-value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID name  Hours
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 MON     8.5
2     1 TUE     8.5
3     1 WED     8.5
4     1 THU     8.5
5     1 FRI     8.5
6     1 FRI     8.5
7     1 SAT     6  
8     1 SUN     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, MON = c(8.5, 9), TUE = c(8.5, 9), WED = c(8.5, 
9), THU = c(8.5, 9), FRI = c(8.5, 9), SAT = c(6, 6), SUN = c(0, 
6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(Day = c("FRI", "SAT", "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", 
"THU", "FRI"), Hours = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Hi, would this still work even if there are more columns before the day columns in df1? and effectively the ID can't be used because the numbers are not in ascending order (in fact their not in any order...can go from 1,4,10,11 etc..) the idea being is I just need to use the first row in df1 for just those columns (MON:SUN) to fill df2...and it will loop until all of df2 is filled with the first rows data from df1....then will move onto the next line in df1 and fill df2 again...Apologies if I should have been clearer in the question